# In Hibernate How to deal with char[] which are specified in bean class and Database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, hibernate

In Hibernate How to deal with `char[]` which are specified in java bean class and Database

Comment: Use a String instead of a char[].

Comment: Thanks Nizet, But i had used String type in Java Bean class and it is mapped to char(4) type in Sql server DB but i am unable to get the result.can u please help me out with the issue.

Comment: Not with so few details. What's your code, what do you expect it to do, and what does it do instead?